# apply function to rows pandas dataframe with different parameters depending on values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[1,True],[2,False]],columns=['A','decide'])
```

to which rows I want to apply a function `fun` depending on the value of the decide column

```
def fun(case,var):
   case = case + var
   return case


df=df.apply(lambda x: fun(x,1) if x['decide'] else fun(x,2))
```

of course doesn't work :) any idea why and how to make it working?

Comment: please share expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to fix your code , PS : You forget to add `axis=1`

```
df.apply(lambda x: fun(x['A'],1) if x['decide'] else fun(x['A'],2),axis=1)
Out[560]: 
0    2
1    4
dtype: int64
```

---

Also When you using `np.where` you still can pass your own defined functions

```
np.where(df.decide,fun(df.A,1),fun(df.A,2))
```

---

If you logic is as simple as you show to us in your sample function

```
df.A+2-df.decide
Out[563]: 
0    2
1    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC you can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['A'] = np.where(df.decide, df.A+1, df.A+2)

   A  decide
0  2    True
1  4   False
```